# How to display my Server Action data to page

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm working with Next.js 14 and exploring the use of Server Actions to interact with the OpenAI API. My goal is to capture user input, send it to the OpenAI API, and then display the API's response on the page within pre tags. While I've successfully managed to send the request to the OpenAI API and receive a response in the console log, I'm struggling to display this response on the page.

Here is my code:

```
export default async function Home() {

  async function getData(formData: FormData) {
    'use server'

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/codelang`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData.get('code')),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      cache: 'no-cache',
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
  
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data.choices)
  
  }  
  
  return (
    <>
      <form action={getData}>
        <input name="code" type="text" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <pre>{data.choices ? "" :""}</pre>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever you want to display on UI, you have to return it on the server action. The same applies to errors. throwing error is not right. your action could be organized like this:

```
async function getData(formData: FormData) {
  "use server";
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/codelang`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData.get("code")),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      cache: "no-cache",
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    // in case you need to return this. but usually actions are used for mutation and data is fetched
    return data.choices;
  } catch (error) {
    return { form_error: "Failed to fetch data" };
  }
}
```

then using `useFormState`:

```
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";

const [formState, action] = useFormState(
    getData,
    { form_error: {} }
  );
```

in jsx

```
{formState.formError ? (Show Error Here) : null
```